# Adding new content to an already existing navigation drawer app in eclipse

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Okay, so I'm fairly new to android development and I'm working on a project for my boss that requires the app to have a navigation drawer. The issue is that all of the pages show the same content(the stuff that's only supposed to be on the first page). My question is how do I go about making all of the pages have different content and where do I put that content? Below is the xml from activity_main.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.google.auditreport.MainActivity" >


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!--
     android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
     android:layout_gravity="left" instead.
-->
<!--
     The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container.
-->

<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <!-- text view for title -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/AuditTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/Title" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLoc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ReportDateTV"
        android:text="@string/Location"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical|center_horizontal|end" />
    <!-- edit text for report scope -->
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/LocET"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtLoc"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtLoc"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" >

    <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <!-- text view for audit date field -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/AuditDatesTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtLoc"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/AuditDates" />

    <!-- edit text for audit dates  -->
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/AuditDateET"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/AuditDatesTV"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/AuditTV"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="date" />

    <!-- edit text for report scope -->
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ScopeET"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ScopeTV"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ScopeTV"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <!-- text view for date of the report -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ReportDateTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ScopeTV"
        android:layout_below="@+id/AuditDatesTV"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/ReportDate" />

    <!-- text view for scope -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ScopeTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ReportDateTV"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/AuditDateET"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/Scope" />

    <!-- text view for exclusions -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ExclusionsTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ScopeTV"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ScopeTV"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/Exclusions" />

    <!-- edit text for exclusions -->
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ExclusionsET"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ExclusionsTV"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ScopeET"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <!-- text view for standard -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/StandardTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ExclusionsTV"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ExclusionsTV"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/Standard" />

    <!-- edit text for standard -->
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/StandardET"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/StandardTV"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ExclusionsET"
        android:ems="10" 
        android:inputType="text" />

    <!-- text view for preparer -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/PrepareTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/StandardTV"
        android:layout_below="@+id/StandardTV"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/Prepare" />

    <!-- edit text for preparer -->
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/PrepareET"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/PrepareTV"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/StandardET"
        android:ems="10" 
        android:inputType="text" />

    <!-- text veiw for serial -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/SerialTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/PrepareTV"
        android:layout_below="@+id/PrepareTV"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/ReportSerial" />

    <!-- edit text for serial -->
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/SerialET"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/SerialTV"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/PrepareET"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:text="@string/SerialNum" />

    <!-- button to poulate the serial number -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSerial"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/SerialET"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/SerialET"
        android:layout_below="@+id/SerialET"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="@string/GetSerial" />

    <!-- text view for "today's" date -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/display"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ScopeTV"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/AuditDateET"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/AuditDateET"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.google.auditreport.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First familiarize yourself with the sample app here http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html.

Then to help you, get going in the right direction, the XML is not the right place to look. Look for something like a BaseActivity.java there you'll find somethink like `navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem...` where a list of all your menu options are added in. You should them be able to find something like a `switch` that runs off those items to define a fragment and then a `FragmentManager` to change the fragment that is being displayed.

Here's an example in my app:

```
/**
 * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
 * */
public void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new ProfileFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new ChartingFragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new DayHistoryFragment();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new WeekFragment();
        break;
    case 4:
        fragment = new TemperatureFragment();
        break;
    case 5:
        fragment = new CalendarFragment();
        break;
    case 6:
        fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
        break;
    case 7:
        fragment = new SettingsFragment();
        break;
    case 8:
        fragment = new DonateFragment();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. I looked at the android site first and the examples there were not very descriptive and a little hard to follow, but this helps put me in the right direction.

Comment: I understand, the examples were a little much for me at first also. You'll get the hang of it! Glad I could help in some small way :)

Comment: After doing a little more digging, I came up with another question. Do I need to create a new fragment for each of the pages I want or can that be done in one xml fragment along with the java select case?

Comment: Have you posted it yet?

Comment: No, I didn't know if that would constitute a new thread, and I haven't looked around here yet to see if a similar one exists.